# Create 2 child processes

Tags: c++, linux, process, pipe, fork

I have to create this kind of communication between 3 processes:

- 1 process(parent) :

  - sends even numbers to child 1;
  - sends uneven numbers to child 2;
  - gets numbers sent from child 1 and child 2
- 2 process(child 1):

  - gets even numbers from parent;
  - sends even numbers to child 2;
  - sends 2*value_of_number to parent
- 3 process(child 2):

  - gets uneven numbers from parent;
  - sends 2*value_of_number to parent

This is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int p12[2],p13[2],p23[2];
    int p21[2],p31[2];

    if(pipe(p12)<0){
        perror("pipe 12 error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pipe(p13)<0){
        perror("pipe 13 error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pipe(p23)<0){
        perror("pipe 23 error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pipe(p21)<0){
        perror("pipe 21 error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pipe(p31)<0){
        perror("pipe 31 error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    switch(fork()){
        case -1:{
            perror("fork 1 error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        case 0:{//1 child
            close(p12[1]);
            close(p13[1]);
            close(p13[0]);
            close(p23[0]);
            close(p21[0]);
            close(p31[1]);
            close(p31[0]);
            int paros;
            int ket;
            while(read(p12[0],&paros,sizeof(int))>0){
                cout<<"2: "<<paros<<endl;
                if(write(p23[1],&paros,sizeof(int))==-1){
                    perror("write 23 error\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                ket=2*paros;
                if(write(p21[1],&ket,sizeof(int))==-1){
                    perror("write 21 error\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            close(p21[1]);
            close(p12[0]);
            close(p23[1]);
            exit(0);
        }
        default:{
            switch(fork()){
                case -1:{
                    perror("fork 2 error\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                case 0:{//2 child
                    close(p13[1]);
                    close(p12[1]);
                    close(p12[0]);
                    close(p23[1]);
                    close(p31[0]);
                    close(p21[1]);
                    close(p21[0]);
                    int szamok;
                    int ket;
                    while(read(p13[0],&szamok,sizeof(int))>0){
                        cout<<"3: "<<szamok<<endl;
                        ket=2*szamok;
                        if(write(p31[1],&ket,sizeof(int))==-1){
                            perror("write 31 error\n");
                            exit(1);
                        }
                    }
                    while(read(p23[0],&szamok,sizeof(int))>0){
                        cout<<"3: "<<szamok<<endl;
                    }
                    close(p31[1]);
                    close(p13[0]);
                    close(p23[0]);
                    exit(0);
                }
                default:{
                    close(p12[0]);
                    close(p13[0]);
                    close(p23[0]);
                    close(p23[1]);
                    close(p21[1]);
                    close(p31[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int i=1;
    while(i<=10){
        if(i%2==0){
            if(write(p12[1],&i,sizeof(int))==-1){
                perror("write 12 error\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(write(p13[1],&i,sizeof(int))==-1){
                perror("write 13 error\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    int szam;
    while(read(p21[0],&szam,sizeof(int))>0){
        cout<<"1: "<<szam<<endl;
    }
    while(read(p31[0],&szam,sizeof(int))>0){
        cout<<"1: "<<szam<<endl;
    }
    close(p12[1]);
    close(p13[1]);
    close(p31[0]);
    close(p21[0]);
    while(wait(NULL)>0){};
    exit(0);
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't work...

Comment: What is the problem you get: what behavior did you expect and what behavior you really get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parent writes 5 numbers into each pipe then waits for all the responses from child 1 before moving on to child 2.  After writing numbers to the children, you don't close those pipes, so those children don't know that the parent has stopped.  In the case of child 1, it is still waiting to receive more numbers from the parent.  Because of that, it won't ever close its own pipes and exit.  The parent, therefore, is stuck in it's first read loop from child 1, and never gets to child two.

After writing into p12[1] and p13[1], add

```
close(p12[1]);
close(p13[1]);
```

and the process will run to completion